# Model state invalid when using custom RegexAttribute

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, enterprise-library

Regex not working in code but works in tool:
`\+?\(?([0-9]{2})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{4})\2([0-9]{4})`

This `regex` is used in Custom Attribute in MVC application. Where it always invalidate the model. While it works accurately in online tools.

I am trying to validate phone number is this format: `+(55) 7564 6242`

Comment: IIRC the attribute automatically anchors the pattern (ie like wrapping it in `^`...`$`). Could that affect your results? If not, please post the attribute definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the language, but from Attribute and MVC I'm guessing C#.

You have to escape your regex strings for the source code.

**Original pattern**

```
\+?\(?([0-9]{2})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{4})\2([0-9]{4})
```

**Regular C# (or Java) String**

```
string pattern = "\\+?\\(?([0-9]{2})\\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{4})\\2([0-9]{4})"
```

**C# verbatim (better for regex / hardcoded Windows paths)**

```
string pattern = @"\+?\(?([0-9]{2})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{4})\2([0-9]{4})"
```

See [C# String Literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090) for more info.

**Without Escape**
An unescaped string would result in a pattern that the regex engine just doesn't recognize (see output below), because `\\` is special in your source language strings. It probably escapes it something like this

```
 string pattern = "\+?\(?([0-9]{2})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{4})\2([0-9]{4})";
 print(pattern);
```

would output (note the missing `\\`s)

> +?(?([0-9]{2}))?([ .-]?)([0-9]{4})2([0-9]{4})

Answer (score 1):

You can use like that.

```
public partial class xxx
{
[RegularExpression(@"^\+?\(?([0-9]{2})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{4})\2([0-9]{4})", ErrorMessage = "")]
public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
}
```